# dynamic id generation using File reader() javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload

i am trying to create multiple image uploader with delete option,till now i am able to select unique multiple files but i want to have a delete option .for that i have to generate an id for each image to delete it before uploading :

```
window.onload = function(){

//Check File API support
if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
{

var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

    var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
   var dive = $(".overview").find('img').length;
    var output = document.getElementById("result");
    // console.log(files);

    for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
    {
        var file = files[i];


        //Only pics
        if(!file.type.match('image'))
          continue;


      $(".overview .imgdivcon").each(function(){

        var its =$(this).children().eq(1).attr("title");
                if(its == file.name ){
                throw alert("already exits") ;

            }
        });
        var divn = i+dive+1;
        var picReader = new FileReader();

        console.log(divn);


        picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

            var picFile = event.target;

            var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.className="imgdivcon";

            div.innerHTML = "<p onclick='sliceimg("+divn+")' class='close' name='"+i+"' id='cl'>x</p><img width='150' height='150' class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                    "title='" + file.name + "'/>";                    
            output.insertBefore(div,null);          
        });   


         //Read the image
        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);



    }                               

});
```

when i'm selecting single image its generating unique id for each image ,but when i'm selecting multiple images it's giving total images count for each image but not a unique count.

here is my js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/aerfan/CdgUV/ little help wil be aprreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got wrong unique id (should be the order of image instead of total count) when you select multiple images because the "divn" variable will be the total count of images when the picReader load event handler being triggered.

Closure will add local variable to its scope when function was created. The outer for loop finished before file reader load callback being executed and divn will be the total count of images.

```
for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
{
    ......
    var divn = i+dive+1;   //this variable will be added to callback closure

    .......

    picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

        ........
        //divn is always the total count of images
        div.innerHTML = "<p onclick='sliceimg("+divn+")' class='close' name='"+i+"' id='cl'>x</p><img width='150' height='150' class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                "title='" + file.name + "'/>";                    
        output.insertBefore(div,null);          
    });
}
```

To solve this problem, you could try to use currying technique. Let's update the picReader load event callback:

```
picReader.addEventListener("load",(function(divn){
    return function(event){
        var picFile = event.target;

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className="imgdivcon";

        div.innerHTML = "<p onclick='sliceimg("+divn+")' class='close' name='"+i+"' id='cl'>x</p><img width='150' height='150' class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                          "title='" + file.name + "'/>";                    
        output.insertBefore(div,null);
    };

})(divn));
```

You can prefill argument (divn) , use closure to remember its status and return new function by using currying.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: thanks it really helped me alot. can u please just provide a reference link to learn currying technique

Comment: You can read Resig's article [partial application in JS](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/).